# How change google map coords with onClick?

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

How can I change coords in google-map?
I want to get zoom for region, when I click on regions Polygon...
When I change it manually in useState (myPlaces) - its work norm after reloading page, but when I change it with onClick on Polyigon component - it doesn't work...

```
 function Map() {
        const [myPlaces, setMyPlaces] = useState([
            { id: "Yerevan", pos: { lat: 40.1872, lng: 44.5152 }, icon: iconSvg1},
            { id: "place2", pos: { lat: 39.5133, lng: 46.3393 }, icon: iconSvg1},
            { id: "place3", pos: { lat: 40.9631, lng: 43.8102 }, icon: iconSvg},
            { id: "place4", pos: { lat: 40.445640, lng: 43.621150 } , icon: iconSvg },
            { id: "place5", pos: { lat: 40.11111, lng: 44.446742 }, icon: icona1  },
            { id: "place6", pos: { lat: 40.44444, lng: 44.55454 }, icon: icona2},
            { id: "place7", pos: { lat: 40.33333, lng: 43.855 } , icon: icona3 },
            { id: "place8", pos: { lat: 40.8888, lng: 44.446742 }, icon: icona4}
        ])

        const changeCoords = () => {
            setMyPlaces([
                { id: "shirak1", pos: { lat: 40.5938216882435, lng: 44.1755297044926 } },
                { id: "shirak2", pos: { lat: 41.0991679960975, lng: 43.4472709450793 } },
                { id: "shirak3", pos: { lat: 40.416456064449, lng: 43.6499091003992 } },
                { id: "shirak4", pos: { lat: 41.1763221361961, lng: 43.9408247420607 } }
            ])
        }

        const fitBounds = map => {
            const bounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    
            myPlaces.map(place => {
                bounds.extend(place.pos);
                return place.id;
            });
    
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        };

        const loadHandler = map => {
            // Store a reference to the google map instance in state
            setMapRef(map);
    
            // Fit map bounds to contain all markers
            fitBounds(map);
        };
    
        const [path, setPath] = useState(regions);

        return (
            <LoadScript  ...>
                <GoogleMap
                  
                    onLoad={loadHandler}
                    ...
                >
                   
                    {
                        regions.map((r, index) => {
                            return <Polygon
                                ...
                                path={path[index].region}
                                onClick={changeCoords}
                            />
                        })
                    }
            </LoadScript>
        );
    }
    
    export default Map
```

Comment: You need to call `fitBounds(map);` after changing the co-ordinates with `onClick`

Comment: I call this function in useEffect , but it doesn't work...